# Parentheses in \overset not working when using breqn

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, breqn

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math} 
        \overset{.}{()}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

In this example parentheses (even a single one) in `\overset` together with `breqn` package throw "undefined control sequence" error when I try to compile it.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You probably want `\dot{()}`. Congratulations, you found another bug in `breqn`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Should the package be renamed `brltx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the parens in an `\hbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
    \begin{math} 
       {\overset{.}{\hbox{()}}}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

Alternately, you can use a stack, perhaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math} 
        \stackon[2pt]{()}{\scriptstyle.}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `stackon` works like a charm! I need to put math symbols in the parens and it seems that `stackon` puts the inner parts in textmode but I solved that by wrapping them in `\(\)`. edit: Aha! I don't have to do such ugly things. I overlooked that `\stackMath` option in your code!

Comment: @VaNa If you need both text and math stacking, you can change modes with `\stackText` and `\stackMath` or you can leave it in `\stackText` mode and just wrap usage with `\ensurestackMath{\stackon[]{}{}}}`